# Prove that if $A$ are well-founded, so are $\cup A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. Prove that if $A$ are well-founded, so are $\cup A$.
2. Prove that every element of a well-founded set is well-founded.

Comment: Well-founded in what ordering? The $\epsilon$-ordering?  Some arbitrary ordering?

Comment: @MJD yes, the ϵ-ordering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in ZFC=ZF+AC with the axiom of regularity then every object(sets) of your universe is well founded. By the axiom of union set, given $A$ set then exists the set $\cup A$ as the set containing the elements of the elements of $A$, so it's a well founded set because is an object of our universe, so is well founded.
By the second part we know that elements of sets are also sets, so they are well founded